# Line integral exercise of a real vector field

Tags: real-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I'm trying to solve the following exercise of a vector field over line integral:

$$\int\limits_C\frac{-y}{4x^2+9y^2}dx+\frac{x}{4x^2+9y^2}dy,$$

where $C$ is the closed curve formed by the equations $y=x^2-1$ and $y=3$, and oriented clock-wise.

I already checked for the field to be conservative, and it isn't. I also thought in using the parametrizations $x=3\cos\theta$ and $y=2\sin\theta$, since the denominator has an elliptic shape, but it doesn't seem right... Also, I don't see that the Green theorem will make it easier than computing the integral over the curve directly.

The result is supposed to be something simple, but I don't have a clue of how to proceed, any help will be very well received :)

PS: as user10354138 pointed out, at least inside the curve I can't use the Green's theorem because of the (0,0) point.

Comment: What happens with Green’s Theorem?

Comment: Hint: Find an ellipse of the form $4x^2+9y^2 = R^2$ for a large enough value of $R$ such that it contains the region in the problem. Then use Green's theorem on the region in between both curves.

Comment: With Green's, beware of something fishy near $(0,0)$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, but I don't see how computing the integral over the region between both curves is easier than computing the region inside the original curve...

Comment: @Fernando Because the region in the problem contains the origin (a singularity of the vector field), so Green's theorem is not defined for this problem and will give you the wrong answer of $0$ if you tried. The fact that the curve in the problem is oriented clockwise is probably a hint from the problem writer to try my hint.

Comment: Yes, @NinadMunshi, you are right! Thanks, I haven't seen that. But then a question remains, the integral over that region seems as complicated as computing the line integral directly.

Comment: That tells me you haven't tried. Actually give the problem an attempt before posting another comment. But feel free to ask about clarifications after the setup.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Conceptually I prefer using $R\ll 1$ rather than $R\gg 1$.

Comment: @user10354138 given the orientation of the ellipse and the shape of the curve in the problem it would be difficult to find nice numbers even though either works. The priority is the nicer calculation since there is no conceptual difference.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake of signal computing the derivatives of $\partial P/\partial y$ and $\partial Q/\partial x$. Now everything make sense. Thanks a lot!